# Websocket: "Invalid frame header" if I send 130+ char as my close message

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket

*I use `ws` node.js module and html5 `WebSocket`*.

Websocket connection starts when user initiates an import and closes when the import was successful or there was an error.

Sometimes error messages are long (130+ charterers)

**In case of these long messages sent via `close` event, Chrome throws a "Invalid frame header" error:**

```
ws.close(1008, 'Really long error Really long error Really long error Really long error Really long errorReally long error Really long error')
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but control frames (aka Close, Ping, Pong) can't be fragmented => [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.4). It looks like Chrome is fragmenting the message because the message is so long.

Answer (score 0):

The websocket specification [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5) states in section 5.5 that

```
All control frames MUST have a payload length of 125 bytes or less
and MUST NOT be fragmented.
```

i.e. control frames can't be fragmented (as stated by [@David Gölzhäuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858656/websocket-invalid-frame-header-if-i-send-130-char-as-my-close-message#comment70238547_38858656)) and their payload length is limited to 125 bytes.

I just sent a close request on a websocket using Chrome and Chrome throws the exception

```
Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The message must not be greater than 123 bytes.
```

But if some library would try to fragment the message or to use an extended length message, then such an error as the one you have seen would be thrown.